# fire and smoke in same domain

Tags: physics, smoke-simulation, fire

i like to create a fire and smoke simulation in one domain with different emitters.
But I can only change the colors from both the smoke and the fire. I like to set different colors for the flames and the smoke.[image]

Answer (score 1):

for 2.79 if you use an attribute node and put in flame or smoke you can add materials for flame and for smoke[image]

Answer (score 0):

another approach for blender 2.8 which i now see you are using is to select the smoke flow object and before putting smoke use object > quick effects > smoke > pop up options - smoke, and for flame flow same but in the pop up options choose fire, or if one flow object for both fire and flame choose fire + smoke[image]